# Get distinct values in mongodb aggregation with lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following collection:
user collection and product collection.
The user can list multiple products.
I want to fetch distinct user_ids only using mongodb aggregation.
Below is the code that I have tied however I am still getting duplicate user_ids

```
    const aggregate = [
    {
      $match: {},
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'user_id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'user',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: '$user',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,  
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        user_id: 1,
      },
    },
  ];
  const data = await ProductModel.aggregate(aggregate).allowDiskUse(
    true
  );
```

Comment: If you `"$project"` only `"user_id"`, your `"$lookup"` is irrelevant, yes?

Comment: Is there any aspect of the `product` collection that is relevant to your goal of getting distinct users? Can there be an entry in `users` who is not referenced in a `user_id` field of a `product` document? Also, do you have sample documents? Hard to really get started assisting here without more details

Comment: can you add sample documents and the expected output?

Comment: Thank you @rickhg12hs Actually lookup was irrelevant.